# Numerical solution of ODE with fixed condition at the final time with Python

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods, ode

I'm trying to solve an ODE of the form

```
x'=f(x), x(T)=x_{T}
```

in python using scipy.integrate.odeint.

However, this has the form:
scipy.integrate.odeint(func, y0, t,...), where y0 is the vector of initial conditions. I do not have an initial vector, instead, I have a vector for the final time T. How should I modify the scipy.integrate.odeint routine?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`odeint` can integrate "backwards".  Give the known value `x(T)` as the "initial" condition, and then give the `t` values in decreasing order from `T` down to wherever you want the solution to stop.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227115/backward-integration-in-time-using-scipy-odeint/13240699#13240699) for an example.