# How to give an arbitrary initial condition on odient in python

Tags: python, scipy, ode, differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a first order linear differential equation in one variable, and am currently using the odient module in scipy.integrate. However, the initial condition it takes in $y_0$ is evaluated at the initial boundary of the domain $x_0$, while what I have is the value of $y$ at some random point $x$.

Suggestions on similar questions were to use solve_bvp, which doesn't quite solve my problem either.

How do I go about this?

Comment: So you want a numerical solution over some interval [a,b], but are given the initial condition y(x_0)=y_0 at some a<x_0<b? You have to call `odeint` two times, once on [a,x_0] integrating backwards, and once on [x_0,b] integrating forward. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227115/backward-integration-in-time-using-scipy-odeint

Answer (score 1):

Numerical integrators always march in only one direction from the initial point. To get a two-sided solution one would have to call the numerical integrator twice, forward and backward, for instance as

```
ta = np.linspace(x0,a,Na+1)
ya = odeint(f,y0,ta)
tb = np.linspace(x0,b,Nb+1)
yb = odeint(f,y0,tb)
```

You can leave these two parts separate for further uses like plotting, or join them into one array each

```
t=np.concatenate([ta[::-1],tb[1:]])
y=np.concatenate([ya[::-1],yb[1:]])
```